# Making my python program an application

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, py2app, requires

I am trying to make my python program an application for mac. So I installed the program

> py2app

I made my script and then I made my "setup.py" script as a you tube tutorial said. But a error message keeps popping up when I enter the next step in the terminal:

(Here is the step I entered)

> python /Users/(my name)/Setup.py py2app

and the error code keeps saying

```
  File "/Users/jonah/Setup.py", line 8
setup_requires=["py2app"],
             ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

here is the code in setup.py:

```
#Script for building the the app
#USAGE: python setup.py py2app

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    app=["Kirby's Dream Test script.py"]
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

How do I make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,` after the `app` field:

```
setup(
    app=["Kirby's Dream Test script.py"], # you need this comma
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a missing comma for starters:

```
setup(
    app=["Kirby's Dream Test script.py"],
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```